# How to synch time between ubuntu laptops in a local network

Tags: networking, server, sync, ntp

I'd like to synch time on all my laptops inside my local network which use a router but it has no access to public internet so I can't use remote time servers.

I would like to use a laptop to act like a NTP server and make all the other laptops to synch to this NTP server.

I'm trying to use ntp and my ntp.conf file is this one:

```
# /etc/ntp.conf, file di configurazione for ntpd

# File nel quale scrivere la frequenza di scostamento dal clock di sistema.
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

# Statistiche
statsdir /var/log/ntpstats/
statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

#server 2.it.pool.ntp.org iburst
#server 1.europe.pool.ntp.org iburst
#server 3.europe.pool.ntp.org iburst

server 192.168.1.11 #my NTP server IP address

# È permesso "dialogare" con chiunque (via ipv4 e via ipv6) ma non sono autorizzate configurazioni
restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery

# Utenti locali
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

but when I run `ntpq -p` on the NTP server laptop it seems it isn't working:

```
 sudo ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 Evangelion01    .INIT.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

Can you help me, please?
I tried to solve this problem for the whole day by looking on google, but I found nothing useful, unfortunately.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [chrony](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/chrony.1.html). It seems a much friendlier solution.

Comment: I tried to study chrony yesterday, but i didn't understand how to configure it. Do I have to create a configuration file with a set of parameters or do I have to use the default one?

Comment: consider using your router as a NTP server

Comment: I've read this: http://chrony.tuxfamily.org/doc/2.3/manual.html#Isolated-networks about chrony but I didn't understand where I have to specify that instructions.

Comment: @pfeiffep: how can I use the router a NTP server? Do i have to put the router address in the ntp.conf file?

Comment: @MarcusBarnet yes you need to edit the configuration file located at `/etc/chrony/chrony.conf`. I would think that the most relevant lines in your case would be `server offline` and `local stratum 10` to indicate that you want `chronyd` to act as an independent time server, which clients are allowed to poll over the local network.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet Apologies for not noticing that you are the same poster as the one about `chrony` yesterday.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet 1st step is check the router manual to discover whether your router is capable

Comment: Are you running `ntpd`, the NTP Server on 192.168.1.11?

Comment: yes, the NTP server in on 192.168.1.11

Comment: I edited my ntp.conf on server side adding these: "server 127.127.1.0 iburst
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10" and not it seems to work. The client is able to synch with the server.

Comment: @MarcusBarnet I suggest answering your own question - please use details

Answer (score 1):

This seem to work. The example uses a C-Network on 192.168.x.x the server being 192.168.0.11

You create the following files /etc/npt.conf

1. on the server

   ```
   driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
   server 127.127.0.1    
   fudge  127.127.0.1  stratum 2
   ```
2. on all others

   ```
   driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
   server 192.168.0.11    
   fudge  127.127.0.1 stratum 3
   ```

Then restart the service with

```
 sudo service ntp restart
```

You set the time on the server only with
sudo date --date="15:30 01 jan 2020"

for me that worked fine. A new client needs a few minutes to pick up the time.